Order of start-up procedure in Piper Dakota PA28-236 between electric pump and mixture
I am flying a Piper Dakota PA28-236. The POH stipulates that for start up the right order is first the electric pump ON and then mixture Rich.
I do not understand the logic behind this. For me, it would make more sense to first put the mixture to rich and then the electric pump ON, in the sense that the fuel could directly go to the cylinders without being blocked.
Could anyone explain the rationale behind this ?

Does the POH state that it must be in this order, or does it just state the steps in an order?  Sometimes there are steps that can be done n any sequence, but some ordering has to be chosen for this printed list.

It states the steps in this order. I have the impression that the vapor lock problem mentioned above might be the answer

The Piper Dakota PA28-236 has a carburetor, not fuel injection. Before starting the engine, with the fuel pump on, and mixture rich, fuel is only going to the carburetor float bowl, not to the cylinders.
The only reason to use the electric fuel pump, before starting, is to insure the carburetor float bowl is full.

The order in which you turn on the fuel pump, or put the mixture to rich, doesn’t really matter as long as both are done before you try to start the engine.
My guess is that Piper decided to put the electric fuel pump first because they felt ensuring the float bowl is full of gas is more important than selecting full rich. (selecting full rich does nothing if there is no fuel in the bowl)
Once the engine is started, the mechanical fuel pump feeds the carb, and the electric fuel pump can be turned off as it is used as a backup only.



thanks for your detailed answer but you are not referring directly to my questions. The question is why the POH indicates during the start up procedure that first you must turn on the electric pump and then set the mixture to rich. I would have expected that first you set the mixture to rich and then you turn the electric pump ON. Thanks in advance for your help

Thanks, I edited my answer with more information and also to add a guess as to why the electric fuel pump is selected on first.

Thanks, what about the vapor lock problem mentioned above? Reading the article I believe it makes sense to first turn on the electric pump, however I agree with you that the impact might also be limited

Vapor lock is more common when starting a hot, fuel injected engine. You will basically never get Vapor lock with a cold, carbureted engine

Following engine manufacturers recommendations are never wrong - they are the people knowing the inner workings best. As to why the suggest a special order, it could be for a specific reason or without reason. I tend to find tha for every recommendation given in a POH not following it has an incident or accident in the history.
